# While using GPU for PyTorch models, getting the CUDA error: Unknown error?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to use a pre-trained model using PyTorch. While loading the model to GPU, it is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model\vgg_model.py", line 45, in <module>
    vgg_model1 = VGGFeatureExtractor(True).double().to(device)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 386, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 193, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 193, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 199, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 384, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() else None, non_blocking)
  File "C:\Users\myidi\Anaconda3\envs\openpose\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 163, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: CUDA error: unknown error
```

I have a Windows 10 Laptop, Nvidia 940m GPU, Latest Pytorch and CUDA Toolkit 9.0 (Also tried on 10.0).

I have tried re-installing the GPU drivers, restarted my machine, re-installed PyTorch, Torchvision and CUDA Toolkit.

While using the following to see if PyTorch is detecting a GPU:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

I am getting the following output: `device(type='cuda')`.

What could be the possible issues? I have tried the solution mentioned here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/20990 and the issue still persists.

I simply put the `torch.cuda.current_device()` after `import torch` but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, this worked by using CUDA Toolkit 10.1. I don't know why the latest one is not the default one on PyTorch website in the section where they provide the commands to download the libraries.

Used the following command to install the libraries: `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`